# Android notifications avoid unnecessary notification update

Tags: java, android, eclipse, notifications

I'm using a service which are being called every single minute in the background. It fetches data using a HTTP Request and then notifies the user about the data via an Notification. The problem is that I don't want an notification to be created if it contains the same data that was already fetched and shown the last time.

I've tried to set like static variables and store the data from the latest request to compare it to the newest fetched data and in that way know if it's the same or not and wherever show the notification or not.

**This is what some of my notification code looks like:**

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(NotificationService.this, MainMenu.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(NotificationService.this, NOTIFICATION_REQUESTS_KEY, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);;
if (!powerManager.isScreenOn())
{
       mWakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "NotificationWakeLock");
       mWakeLock.acquire(10000);
       WakeLock mWakeLockCPU = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "NotificationCPUWakeLock");
       mWakeLockCPU.acquire(10000);
}
nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_REQUESTS_KEY, notification);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save contentText locally, every time you get the data from the server, before notifying the user, make sure if it's a different contentText. If it's the same do not notify.

Comment: I don't see how I should store that contentText cause as I understood the service is created in a new Instance every time it's called. Otherwise it would have been the exact same thing as store the data into static variables as I wrote I've already tried above.